# XCode or make - what should I use?

Tags: xcode, makefile

I started my career on Linux/Unix, and moved over to Windows and Visual Studio. XCode feels pretty alien to me. My feeling is that I'm not in control with XCode. It could be the case that I simply haven't understood how to use the IDE, I *am* new at developing for Apple OSs. One thing that kind of irks me, is that nobody seem to have found a clean way to compile for multiple platforms (iOS and Mac OS X), using the same sources. I've found two ways to "hack it", but the hacks sound fragile.

I've been pondering the idea of using simple make files instead of XCode (except for the occasional use of Interface Builder).

Is this a sane route to go? Has anyone done this? Are there any major drawbacks I need to be aware of before I take the leap, or should I just bite the bullet and wait for the enlightenment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xcode, use as many high-level tools as possible. The "loss of control" is replaced by more focus on the application, which IMHO is a great tradeoff.

It is kind of like the loss of control when I went from assembly code to "C", but it was worth it. We keep moving to higher level of abstraction and that allows us to accomplish more, focus on the big picture instead of the minor details.

Comment: Not being able to target both iOS and Mac OS X using the same code base in a reliable way takes a big stab at the big picture though. :(

Comment: I think I have totally misunderstood Xcode. I got it to do what I wished for, and then some. I'll stick with Xcode!

Answer (score 0):

You've just got to learn new ways of doing things. For example, in the situation you describe (building an OS X and iOS app with shared code), I'd put any shared code into a library/framework that is used by both projects, and create a workspace that contains all three projects.

The loss of control you speak of is offset by the fact that this can all be set up without knowing anything about compiler command-line options in around 10 minutes.

It's a different way of thinking, and it can be frustrating if you know how you *would* do it on a different platform, but there are advantages to both options. You may never have to think about the build process again!

Comment: Putting code into a library/framework is very brittle if my google research has come anywhere near reality. I found an article that basically says that you have to trick Xcode in order to share same source files between different platforms (iOS and OSX), in such a way that you don't have to add the *same files* to different projects. Maybe I've totally misunderstood Xcode (probably most likely :).